# Coded ui Test Unable to find a DateTime picker in an Hierarchy

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I’ve 3 Date Time Pickers in a form. I want to select the 2<sup>nd</sup> Date Time Picker but on playback it always selects the 1<sup>st</sup> Date Time picker in the hierarchy. I’ve tried giving all the search properties but no success.

Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Can we see some code maybe?

Comment: I’ve 3 Date Time Pickers “Date time produced”, ”Date time found” and “Date time deposited” .
I’ve to select “Date time deposited” as this is mandatory but coded ui test selects “Date time produced” while playback.

Comment: I’ve used the following code:
Mouse.Click(uIDatetimeDepositedPerDropDown, new Point(38, 6));
Keyboard.SendKeys(uIItem090220120000DropDown, this.Create_ExhibitParams.UIItem090220120000DropDownSendKeys, ModifierKeys.None);